# Application launcher icon being displayed on action bar of an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

On my action bar application icon is being displayed, I don't want it to appear on action bar.
I have modified the androidmanifest.xml and removed `android:icon` from activity element, even then the icon is being displayed?

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.storelocator.StoreLocatorActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call  `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false)` in your activity.  That will hide the icon.

Comment: It's a method on ActionBar in 3.0 and later.  (Edit:  originally said Activity, that's wrong).