# How to remove ic_launcher.png from activity_main?

Tags: android, eclipse

Just started to learn basic Android programming. Trying to create a navigation drawer (which has been done), but my drawer icon is out of place and I want to remove the little green android icon at the top left. Don't wanna just delete the image from the drawable folder in case I decide to add one after all. How can I hide/remove this icon through the xml/java files, and how would I shift the drawer icon into place?
[image]

Comment: Set your actionbar icon to null. Something like `actionBar.setIcon(null);`

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252354/how-to-customize-the-back-button-on-actionbar/9265774#9265774

Comment: Check this links:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15715309/application-launcher-icon-being-displayed-on-action-bar-of-an-activity

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720715/remove-application-icon-and-title-from-honeycomb-action-bar

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11430712/hide-application-launcher-icon-in-title-bar-when-activity-starts-in-android